# How do I use multiple list()/each() calls in a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm working with 3 different arrays (although I'm only testing with two for the time being) and I'm trying to process the arrays on `$_POST`.  I'm currently using:

```
while(list($key_member,$member)=each($_POST['member_ids']) 
    && list($key_amount,$amount)=each($_POST['payment_amounts']))
{
    echo "MEMBER: $member<br>";
    echo "AMOUNT: $amount<br><br>";
}
```

If I use one `list()` on either array it will print the info for that particular item.  However, if I attempt to use multiple `list()` commands in the while, only the last  `list()`ed item gets filled properly.  Is `list()` doing some trickery in the background that's preventing it from working in a while loop?

Obviously the "easy" solution would be to use an index and simply force the issue, but I prefer enumerating -- and I'm honestly just curious as to

What am I doing wrong, and/or what is "broken" with `list()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bug? dunno.
here's a workaround.

```
while(list($key_member,$member)=each($_POST['member_ids'])){
   list($key_amount,$amount)=each($_POST['payment_amounts']);
   echo "MEMBER: $member<br>";
   echo "AMOUNT: $amount<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: Haha, mind reader.  That's actually what I ended up doing.  Although my OCD brain is still wondering what I'm doing wrong in the initial while.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract each array's keys using array_keys(), which produces an indexed array, then keep separate loop counters for each array:

```
$member_ids = array_keys($_POST['member_ids']);
$amounts = array_keys($_POST['payment_amounts']);

$mi = 0;
$am = 0;
while(1) {
   ...

   $mi++
   $am++;
   if (count($member_ids) >= $mi) && (count(amounts) >= $am) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is evaluated in a short-circuit manner, the first statement to return false jumps out of it. In your case it stops to iterate as soon as the first array is at its end. `list` should work fine here, as it's a language construct which assigns variables.

Comment: Yup, aware of that.  However, I always initially use "best case" test-cases that always evaluate to true, just to see if the logic even works.  I have all fields filled in, and, testing the arrays independently, everything is fine.  However, when I combine any two via && things go boom.  Any other ideas?

Comment: maybe you can exchange && to and ? [php.net](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)